# Calculate diameter of rolled paper or carpet, from only the flat area dimensions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm struggling with where to start on this problem,

We need to calculate the diameter of a rolled carpet, from only the flat area dimensions, given only that the carpet is 4m by 12m, and 1.8cm thick when laid flat, what will its diameter be once rolled?

We would assume a standard thickness that it would be rolled around, and allow for some tolerance.  I also assume the weight wouldn't change.

I've tagged this in JS as it would be my preferred language for examples, but not required.

It's a mathsy problem really, that I'm trying to solve with code.

Comment: Why do you think that volume would change after rolling?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no relation to programming

Comment: its an algorithm that needs to be programmed,

Comment: we're transitioning from a flat carpet to the carpet rolled up.  and need to know what the volume would be of that roll

Comment: The formula you're looking for is here: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.08/h/john4.html. It's amazing what you can find with a simple query to a search engine.

Comment: i also agree that the volume stays the same; i have given some explanations here: https://ibb.co/dhzhNS

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for the link, I eventually posted this question after only finding the inverse calculations. I appreciate it despite the unnecessary tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume won't change much, so:

```
Volume = length * width * thickness + volume of the tube it is rolled around.
```

Assuming the rolled up carpet is a cylinder with diameter and width:

```
diameter = sqrt((length * thickness + pi * tube diameter * tube diameter / 4) * 4 / pi)
```

The area of the circular cross section of the rolled-up carpet, `diameter * diameter * pi / 4`, is the same as the area of the circular cross section of the tube, `tube diameter * tube diameter * pi / 4` plus the area of the edge of the carpet, `thickness * length`:

```
diameter * diameter * pi / 4 = length * thickness + pi * tube diameter * tube diameter / 4
```

I then solve for the diameter.

Comment: no, I don't think you understand.  I have the width, and length, rolled out, and need to know the dimension of the carpet roll once its been rolled.

Comment: @pushplaybang You mean the dimensions. The width is same as the width of the carpet. I've added a formula for the diameter.

Comment: @pushplaybang Missed a `/ 4` in the diameter calculation. Added it now.

Comment: yes, this is what I was after - not volume, sorry but volumetric dimensions, width obviously the same, but the diameter is what I needed to calculate the rest.  cheers.

Comment: Lindbåck - can you explain your calc for diameter  a little more?

Comment: @pushplaybang Good thing you asked. There was an error in my calculation - `4/pi` should be inside the square root. Amended my answer and added another step in the explanation.